# the app keep the loading dialog when goes to stop() codename one

Tags: background, dialog, download, codenameone

im having a problem when the app is down. the function stop() in the file "my application" save the current Form, but when i try to make a download and i put the app in background task , when try go back to the app , the app is keeping the dialog "loading" forever... i don't know how to finish the current download in background and show the next Form when go back to the app.

the code of "myapplication" file:

```
private Form current;
public void start() {
            if(current != null){
                current.show();
                return;

            }


            new StateMachine("/theme");

    }

    public void stop() {
        current =  Display.getInstance().getCurrent();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like:

```
if(current instanceof Dialog) {
    current = null;
}
```